# Creating the Client Control Object for ldapjs server side sorting

Tags: openldap, ldapjs

Has anyone has success using the server side sorting control with ldapjs? The docs don't provide any specific examples of creating/using such a control object.

I have enabled the overlay on the openldap server side, but can't seem to come up with the proper format for the client control. I am not sure of the correct format for the Buffer value to create the SortKeyList as mentioned in [RFC 2891](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2891)

```
 const stringBuf = Buffer.from( 'uid' );

            // The LDAP the Server-Side Sorting Control
            const controls = new ldap.ldapjs.Control( {
                "type": "1.2.840.113556.1.4.473",
                "criticality": true,
                "value": stringBuf
            } );
```

I receive the following error:

```
searchErr: TypeError: argument must be a string (was: object)
at Writer.writeString (/srv/node_modules/asn1/lib/ber/writer.js:134:11)
at Control.toBer (/srv/node_modules/ldapjs/lib/controls/control.js:50:27)
at /srv/node_modules/ldapjs/lib/messages/message.js:99:9
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at SearchRequest.LDAPMessage.toBer (/srv/node_modules/ldapjs/lib/messages/message.js:98:19)
at Client._sendSocket (/srv/node_modules/ldapjs/lib/client/client.js:1255:31)
at Client._send (/srv/node_modules/ldapjs/lib/client/client.js:1148:17)
at sendRequest (/srv/node_modules/ldapjs/lib/client/client.js:607:17)
at Client.search (/srv/node_modules/ldapjs/lib/client/client.js:636:5)
at client.starttls (/srv/nodeserver.dev/ldap.js:105:24)
```

I've consulted [function ldapjs.ServerSideSortingRequestControl (options)](https://npmdoc.github.io/node-npmdoc-ldapjs/build/apidoc.html#apidoc.element.ldapjs.ServerSideSortingRequestControl) and also [function ldapjs.Control (options)](https://npmdoc.github.io/node-npmdoc-ldapjs/build/apidoc.html#apidoc.module.ldapjs.Control) to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this working by switching from the generic [ldapjs.Control](https://npmdoc.github.io/node-npmdoc-ldapjs/build/apidoc.html#apidoc.module.ldapjs.Control) to the specific [ldapjs.ServerSideSortingRequestControl](https://npmdoc.github.io/node-npmdoc-ldapjs/build/apidoc.html#apidoc.element.ldapjs.ServerSideSortingRequestControl)

You can provide just the value for the SortKeyList. Type OID will be appended by the function. Criticality can be omitted.

```
const control = { "value": { "attributeType": "uid", "orderingRule": "CaseIgnoreOrderingMatch" } };

const controls = new ldap.ldapjs.ServerSideSortingRequestControl( control );
```

But be aware that this is not a very performant solution